# ES6 import nested function - mocha

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, automation, mocha.js, chai

I am using ES6, and I want to start testing using mocha & chai.

My current test file code is :

```
const assert = require('chai').assert;
var app = require('../../../../src/app/login/loginController').default;


describe('login Controller tests', function(){
    it('no idea ', function(){
        let result = app();
        assert.equal(result, 'hello');
    })
})
```

and my loginController.js is :

```
class LoginController {

    checkout(){
        return 'hello';
    }
}
export default LoginController
```

I want to import the 'checkout' function into a variable inside my test file, but so far I am able to import only the class.

Will appreciate any help, thanks !

Comment: Don't you just create a `new LoginController()` instance in your test then call the function on that instance?

Comment: Yeah but I don't need an instance, I need only the function. Is it possible to have an imported function into a variable ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Static function declaration and the normal function declaration in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45594196/difference-between-static-function-declaration-and-the-normal-function-declarati)

Comment: It makes no sense to 'just import a method' from object. If you want just a function then why to have in in object ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot import methods directly from classes. If you want to import a function without a class as intermediary, then you need to define the function outside the class. Or if you really meant `checkout` to be an instance method, then you need to call it on an instance.

Here's an example file derived from yours:

```
export class LoginController {

    // Satic function
    static moo() {
        return "I'm mooing";
    }

    // Instance method
    checkout() {
        return "hello";
    }
}

// A standalone function.
export function something() {
    return "This is something!";
}
```

And a test file that exercises all functions, adapted from the file you show in your question:

```
const assert = require('chai').assert;

// Short of using something to preprocess import statements during
// testing... use destructuring.
const { LoginController, something } = require('./loginController');

describe('login Controller tests', function(){
    it('checkout', function(){
        // It not make sense to call it without ``new``.
        let result = new LoginController();
        // You get an instance method from an instance.
        assert.equal(result.checkout(), 'hello');
    });

    it('moo', function(){
        // You get the static function from the class.
        assert.equal(LoginController.moo(), 'I\'m mooing');
    });

    it('something', function(){
        // Something is exported directly by the module
        assert.equal(something(), 'This is something!');
    });
});
```